# QuestDB can't read data it just returned

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, questdb

I'm working in Python in a Jupyter Notebook and using data from a QuestDB instance.

The helper function I've defined to read data:

```
def query(q):
    r = requests.get(f"http://{ip}:{port}/exp?query="+q)
    rawData = r.text
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(rawData))
    return df
```

So using this query on the data:

```
query("select * from users")
```

Yields:

[image]

But if we then try to query back that data for the specific `user_id` returned:

```
query("select * from users where user_id = 72")
```

What is returned is a `No query text` error from QuestDB:

[image]

I already tried altering the data type, i.e. `'72'` instead of `72`. What is weird is that I have other much more complex queries that work on other fields of the same table and return results.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when you add the `where user_id = 72` part to the query the second `=` sign messes the HTTP request up and QuestDB does not receive the `query` param at all.
Hence the `No query text` error.

I suggest you try to encode the URL before passing it to requests.get().
It would look something like this:

```
def query(q):
    r = requests.get(f"http://{ip}:{port}/exp?query="+requests.utils.quote(q))
    rawData = r.text
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(rawData))
    return df
```